# Sort numbers by string

Tags: mysql

Hi I am using an API from Postcode Anywhere, the idea being to add a company by searching by postcode to select the address, this is pretty standard and the code works fine.

Just some background info, PAW works in two stages, 1 the post code search criteria is sent off to their services, which returns an array of possible addresses, you then select the address you want, and in stage 2, the full PAF file for that ID is returned and stored to the table.

The problem I am having is that the array they send includes an Address Field which includes house number and street address in one field, making it difficult to sort alphanumerically.

This is the sample data I have in my table:

[image]

and this is how it looks in my application:

[image]

As you can see it is not ideal and I have no control on how they send the data.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can search a string based on numbers that can be 1, 11, 2, instead of 01, 02, 03, etc, or at the very least be able to split this into two rows.  Also please note, that it most cases, the post code search will result business/property names as well as house numbers, as seen in this example.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually I think I have found the answer here ORDER BY CAST(StreetAddress as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a different API provider for the data, Allies Computing (who I work for) have a single step API, where the initial postcode search returns all fields in the response. It also orders these results by premise number/name.

Give it a try here - https://developers.alliescomputing.com/postcoder-web-api/address-lookup/premise

There are also other providers of PAF data that do it this way such as Crafty Clicks and Ideal Postcodes.

It might also be worth checking the PAF license with your provider to ensure you comply with that too.